# Accessing variables inside Eventlisteners - Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 divs with same class but different textContent
I want to extracts its value using eventListners and pass it as a argument to another function

Html Code

```
<div class = "seasonDeatils__container">
 <p class = "seasonYear ">2020</p>
</div>
<div class = "seasonDeatils__container">
 <p class = "seasonYear ">2019</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code I tried

```
var season;
const getSeasonYear = document.querySelectorAll('.seasonDeatils__container');
getSeasonYear.forEach((el)=>{
   el.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
   season =  el.firstElementChild.textContent;
    })
})

//I now want to access the 'season' value elsewhere in the code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the value of `season` as an argument from inside your click listener function itself to a function elsewhere in your code as follows:

```js
var season;
const getSeasonYear = document.querySelectorAll('.seasonDeatils__container');

getSeasonYear.forEach((el)=>{
   el.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
     season =  el.firstElementChild.textContent;
     someOtherFunction(season);
   })
})

someOtherFunction = x => {
    console.log(x);
    alert(x);
}
```

```html
<div class = "seasonDeatils__container">
 <p class = "seasonYear ">2020</p>
</div>
<div class = "seasonDeatils__container">
 <p class = "seasonYear ">2019</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have another doubt regarding this, What if i want to accesses the season value outside that for each function and update the value on each click?.

Comment: In the above snippet, the argument taht you pass gets updated every time you click. Run the snippet above and click 2019 first and then click 2020 to see what I mean.

Comment: Yeah I get it, I want to ask                                                          var season;
const getSeasonYear = document.querySelectorAll('.seasonDeatils__container');
getSeasonYear.forEach((el)=>{
   el.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
     season =  el.firstElementChild.textContent;
     someOtherFunction(season);
   })
})`                                                                                                                                    In this code the season value i receive, I want to pass it on to new file and save there as a variable so is it possible?